# Reallocation of Multi-dimensonal Pointer Array Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, c-strings

First, I'll explain why I'm doing this the way that I am. I'm taking a course in computer programming and my professor has given us an assignment where we have to make an array of records(each contains a first name, last name, & score), and then allow the user to manipulate the records using menu options. All of this MUST be done using only pointer arrays, and structures are not allowed. I *know* it is a headache. I *know* it probably one of the most difficult ways to accomplish this, but its what the professor wants.

With that out of the way, below is what I have for my main function so far. most of the long printf functions are just me printing debugging information. Please take note of the declaration of the char*** variable. It is meant to function as a 3D array where `nameRecords[0]` would be the first record, `nameRecords[0][0]` would be the first name of the first record, and `nameRecords[0][1]` is the last name of the first record. The third dimension is `nameRecords[0][0][21]`, as the strings are only meant to be 20 characters long plus null character.

```
int main(void)
{
    char ***nameRecords = NULL;
    float *scores = NULL;
    int size = 0; // total number of records
    int usrInt = 0;
    while(usrInt < 1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number of records to record(min 1):  ");
        scanf("%d", &usrInt);
        inpurge();

        if(usrInt < 1) printf("\nMust be integer greater than 1.\n");
    }

    nameRecords = (char***)calloc((size), sizeof(char**));
    scores = (float*)calloc(size, sizeof(float));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < usrInt; i++)
    {
        addRecord(&nameRecords, &scores, &size);
        printf("\nnameRecords@%p :: nameRecords[%d]@%p :: nameRecords[%d][0]=%s :: nameRecords[%d][1]=%s\n", nameRecords, size - 1, nameRecords[size - 1], size - 1, nameRecords[size - 1][0], size - 1, nameRecords[size - 1][1]);
    }

    printf("\nnameRecords[0]@%p\n", nameRecords[0]);

    prntRecords(nameRecords, scores, size);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The trouble comes after I pass, for the **SECOND TIME**, `&nameRecords` into the `addRecord` function, defined below. To clarify, the segmentation fault is not received if the user chooses to enter only 1 entry at the beginning of the main function, and the program actually runs and terminates as expected.

```
void addRecord(char ****records, float **scores, int *size)
{   
    printf("\t(*records)[0]%p\n", (*records)[0]);
    ++*size; // increment total number of records by 1
    int index = (*size) - 1;

    char ***tempNames = (char***)realloc(*records, (*size) * sizeof(char**)); // reallocate larger space.
    if(tempNames != *records)
        *records = tempNames; // set original pointer to new value.

    printf("\n\tsize - 1 = %d\n", index);

    float *tempScores = (float*)realloc(*scores, (*size) * sizeof(float)); // reallocate larger space.
    if(tempScores != *scores)
        *scores = tempScores; // set original pointer to new value.

    printf("\ttempNames[0]@%p\n", tempNames[0]);

    tempNames[index] = (char**)calloc(tempNames[index], 2 * sizeof(char*));
    enterRecord(tempNames[index], scores[index]);

    printf("\n\ttempNames@%p :: tempNames[0]@%p :: tempNames[%d][0]=%s :: tempNames[%d][1]=%s\n", tempNames, tempNames[0], index, tempNames[index][0], index, tempNames[index][1]);
    printf("\n\t*records@%p :: *records[0]@%p :: *records[%d][0]=%s :: *records[%d][1]=%s\n", *records, (*records)[0], index, (*records)[index][0], index, (*records)[index][1]);

    return;
}
```

Below is an example output of the program. Without taking too long to explain whats happening, the tabbed lines are the lines of output from within the `addRecord` function. Specifically, the pointer to the first record, `record[0]`, has been turned into a garbage value on the second pass through the `addRecord` function, just after the `enterRecord` function.

```
Enter the number of records to record(min 5):  2
        (*records)[0](nil)

        size - 1 = 0
        tempNames[0]@(nil)

Enter first name: 1

Enter last name: 1

Enter score: 1

COMPLETE enterRecord

        tempNames@0x6387010 :: tempNames[0]@0x6387050 :: tempNames[0][0]=1 :: tempNames[0][1]=1

        *records@0x6387010 :: *records[0]@0x6387050 :: *records[0][0]=1 :: *records[0][1]=1

nameRecords@0x6387010 :: nameRecords[0]@0x6387050 :: nameRecords[0][0]=1 :: nameRecords[0][1]=1
        (*records)[0]0x6387050

        size - 1 = 1
        tempNames[0]@0x6387050

Enter first name: 2

Enter last name: 2

Enter score: 2

COMPLETE enterRecord

        tempNames@0x6387010 :: tempNames[0]@0x40000000 :: tempNames[1][0]=2 :: tempNames[1][1]=2

        *records@0x6387010 :: *records[0]@0x40000000 :: *records[1][0]=2 :: *records[1][1]=2

nameRecords@0x6387010 :: nameRecords[1]@0x63870b0 :: nameRecords[1][0]=2 :: nameRecords[1][1]=2

nameRecords[0]@0x40000000

records@0x6387010 :: records[0]@0x40000000
Segmentation fault
```

All of the debug information points to the `enterRecord` function as being the culprit. So here it is, the evil `enterRecord` function...

```
void enterRecord(char **names, float *score)
{
    names[0] = (char*)calloc(21, sizeof(char)); // allocate first name string
    names[1] = (char*)calloc(21, sizeof(char)); // allocate last name string

    printf("\nEnter first name: ");
    fgets(names[0], 21, stdin);
    if(strlen(names[0]) == 20) // IGNORE. just handles overflow from fgets.
        inpurge();
    remNewLine(names[0]); // removes '\n' character at end of string

    printf("\nEnter last name: ");
    fgets(names[1], 21, stdin);
    if(strlen(names[1]) == 20) // IGNORE. just handles overflow from fgets.
        inpurge();
    remNewLine(names[1]); // removes '\n' character at end of string

    printf("\nEnter score: ");
    scanf("%f", score);
    inpurge();

    printf("\nCOMPLETE enterRecord\n");
    return;
}
```

Only... no attempt at altering the affected pointer was made. The pointer value to the second element of the records array(`records[1]`) was passed into the function, and nothing I can see is altering the value of the pointer of the first element of the records array(`records[0]`), though the value of `records[0]` is what's causing the segfault.

I am very sorry for the length and all obfuscatory code. Again, this seems like a terrible approach to writing this program, but its what the situation calls for. I just feel bad for the poor teacher's aide who has to grade 30+ of these assignments.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: There are probably other problems. But the first one I see is that "size" is 0 when the two callocs are called in main. You should always check the return value of allocation functions BTW.

Comment: this line: 'if(usrInt < 1) printf("\nMust be integer greater than 1.\n");' has the problem that the printed text does not match the condition in the 'if'.  The 'if' says <1 is bad.  the text says must be greater than 1.  What about when the entered value is 1?

Comment: @Alan Au `size` is actually determined by the user and must be 1 or greater.

Comment: a few pointers:  1) always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fgets() to assure the input operation was successful 3) in C, do not cast the returned value from calloc().  It is a void* so can be automatically assigned to any other pointer.  4) always check (!=NULL)the returned value from calloc() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @ManicCure Ok, I see what you are doing now. But it still doesn't make sense. Why have the callocs at the start and then immediately overwrite that with realllocs. But you are right, that isn't going to cause  you a SEGV (just makes the program a bit confusing).

Comment: when you see code with 3 or more '*' in a pointer declaration, then there is (probably) something wrong with the code and it needs a redesign.

Comment: @AlanAu I see what you are talking about now. I fixed it in the code, segfault still persists though.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the advice about checking the return values of fgets and calloc. As for the redesign, at this point I'm trying to avoid it. I've got a version using 2 seperate char** types instead to hold the name strings on the back burner.

Comment: Why do you need realloc at all? You already know the number or records once the user has entered it. Why can't you just do the entire calloc in one go at the beginning (that's what I thought you were doing originally)?

Comment: @AlanAu Ah, sorry for the confusion. The addRecord function works this way because eventually the main program will be re-written to allow the user to add even more records to the original array. So, to test this functionality, and to reduce the amount of code, I chose to initialize the records list this way.

Answer (score 1):

this problem seems to be better implemented as

```
#define MAX_FIRST_NAME_LEN (21)
#define MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN  (21)
#define MAX_SCORES         (10)

// in file global memory...
static char **ppFirstNames = NULL; 
static char **ppLastName   = NULL;
static int  **ppScores     = NULL;
static int    numOfEntries = 0;

// in the record input function, which needs NO parameters
scanf ( "%d", &numOfEntries );
if scanf fails, exit

ppFirstNames = malloc (numOfEntries*sizeof char*);
if malloc fails, exit

memset (ppFirstName, '\0', numOfEntries*sizeof char* );

ppLastName = malloc (numOfEntries*sizeof char*);
if malloc fails, free all, exit

memset (ppLastName, '\0', numOfEntries*sizeof char* );

ppScores = malloc (numOfEntries *sizeof int* );
if malloc fails, free all, exit

for(int i=0; i<numOfEntries; i++ )
    ppFirstNames[i] = malloc( MAX_FIRST_NAME_LEN );
    if malloc fails free all, exit

    memset ( ppFirstNames[i], '\0', MAX_FIRST_NAME_LEN );

    ppLastName[i] = malloc (MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN);
    if malloc fails free all, exit

    memset ( ppLastName[i], '\0', MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN );

    ppScores[i] = malloc (MAX_SCORES *sizeof int);-1
    if malloc fails, free all, exit

    memset (ppScores[i], '\0', MAX_SCORES *sizeof int );
end for

for ( int i=0; i < numOfEntries; i++ )
    now read each record
    scanf( "%(MAX_FIRST_NAME_LEN-1)s", ppFirstNames[i] );
    if scanf fails, free all, exit

    scanf( "%(MAX_LAST_NAME_LEN-1)s", ppLastNames[i] );
    if scanf fails, free all exit

    for( int j=0; j< MAX_SCORES; j++ )
        now read this students scores
        int tempScore;  
        scanf( "%d", tempScore );
        if scanf fails, free all, exit

        if -1 == tempScore ) break;

        ppScores[i][j] = tempScore;
    end for
end for
```

The above is the pseudo code for inputting the records

and should be enough to get the input correct.

printing the info thereafter should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Example to use realloc for array multidimensional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size_initial = 10;
    int **ptr;
    int i, j;

    ptr = (int**) malloc(sizeof (int*) * size_initial);

    for (i = 0; i < size_initial; i++) {

    ptr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * 10);

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        ptr[i][j] = i+j;
}

/* realloc +10 */

ptr = (int**) realloc(ptr, sizeof (int*) * (size_initial * 2));

for (i = size_initial; i < size_initial * 2; i++) {

    ptr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int) * 10);

        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            ptr[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}

/* print values */
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        printf("ptr[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this example has a couple of problems.  1) in C, do no cast the returned value from malloc (and family)  2) the value returned from realloc should be assigned to a temp pointer, check for !=NULL, and if not NULL then assigned to the target pointer.  Otherwise, the original pointer will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: There's always someone wanting to appear ... I'm used to it. Where is memory loss? You are really criticizing only to find ... I want to show where memory loss.

Comment: you say that cuz realloc may return null ... man this is an example in no time I made error checking, does the to understand that it is an example and not a code for an OS

Comment: Another problem here is the amount of memory allocated doesn't match up. In the first allocation you allocate `sizeof (int*) * size_initial`, and in the subsequent allocations you allocate `size_initial` lots of `sizeof (int) * 10` bytes, so in total you're allocating `size_initial * (sizeof (int *) + sizeof (int) * 10)` bytes, but an `int[size_initial][10]` only occupies `size_initial * sizeof (int) * 10` bytes (there's no need to allocate `sizeof (int *)`). Furthermore, arrays are single allocations; what you're allocating here is more like a tree.